# How to sync my local files in a shared Google drive folder?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, google-shared-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

I have been given access to a shared Google Drive folder. I want to download the content of that Google drive, modify / add / remove content in that on regular basis on my local machine.

I want to automatically sync up the changes in the Google drive itself in the same shared Google drive folder as it's being used by multiple users. How can I do it?

Comment: this question needs an update

Comment: Questions about using installable clients are better suited for sites about installable apps, in the case of Google Drive [su], [apple.se], [android.se]. Still, the target question used to close as duplicate is relevant because files were migrated from being able to have multiple locations to file and folder shortcuts.

Answer (score 14):

Select the folder in *Shared with me* on a computer, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. You can then add the folder to *My Drive*. You can sync folders in *My Drive* with your computer by using [Drive for desktop](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

Comment: I don't really like my answer. I stopped using Google Drive just as shortcuts were implemented (and switched to Dropbox). Please see my other answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146301/109353  which I think is a better answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't like your answer. It works perfectly for me and syncs the files back to the original sharer. But it's not a shortcut that has been created, it looks like a proper folder. In the context menu I can only find the option to create a shortcut (which doesn't help here), but SHIFT + Z works as you suggested!

Comment: Now that Google has indeed killed Backup and Sync (https://twitter.com/rafa_borges/status/1481763973045358594), this solution has stopped working.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers the problem is that 'shortcuts' have replaced file sharing. In [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146301/109353), I explain that (I think) regular files aren't synced locally, so an alternate version control system is needed, such as a [Google Workspace shared drive](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351), Git, Dropbox, etc.