# How can I access to "shared with me" folders?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

Obviously, shared with me folders are visible on the Google Drive web, but I cannot find them on my local Google Drive for Desktop. One suggestion online was to create a shortcut on my own Google Drive, but it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about installable clients of Google Drive belongs to [su] or [apple.se], [android.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [a recent change (from around April 2020)](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models). Previously, one was able to add files and folders from "Shared with me" to one's Drive. This made syncing other people's files with one's computer's hard drive easy. However, **items can no longer be placed in more than one folder**. This does simplify syncing, as far less data is used to sync a shortcut, compared to large items.

In addition, it prevents people from believing that other people's files are permanent. It is always possible for the other person to permanently delete their files (often this would simply arise from technical reasons, such as deleting their account, reducing storage, or accidents, rather than an unkind decision). To ensure that you keep someone else's files permanently, make a copy. If its parent is "Shared with me", right-click on the file and select "Make a copy". If its parent is a shared folder, select the files you want to copy, right click on the selected files and select "Make a copy". In both cases, the copies will be placed in "My Drive", which you should move to a sub-folder. Unfortunately, entire folders can't be copied at once using the features in the Web app, although you could download the folder, then upload it to your Drive, instead.

For files that are not Google Docs editors, when edit access is granted to other people's files, it appears that Google Drive now expects users to manually upload edits, through the Web app. (This is done by right-clicking on the file > Manage versions > Upload new version.) In my opinion, this makes collaboration more difficult compared to before, when items could be added to My Drive. An alternative is to use Github, or to use [G Suite's shared drives](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351).

Comment: Yes, not having access to shared folders only on web app is a pain. So, I am concluded that it is not possible, and I ended up uploading files to my own drive.

Comment: @Mahdiar do you know about the "Make a copy" option for files, in the right-click menu?

Comment: yes, thanks! That would make a copy of files and moving things much easier, but make a copy option does not work on folders.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer if I have given you useful information. :)

Comment: Thanks @ahorn! Your answer and comment were both helpful, unfortunately my points are not enough to upvote your answer.  I will mark it as accepting answer.

Comment: I can't downvote because just joined, but this requires downvoting: The other answers are correct! No need to copy, or do weird version uploading: You can just add a shortcut.

Comment: @Georg, the question is asking about syncing offline files locally, not online Google Docs. Think about where the data is stored. :)

Comment: Updates to files using non-google formats could be handled with the help of Google Drive installable clients (Google Drive for Desktop for macOS and Windows, and the Android and iPhone and iPad apps for mobile devices).

Comment: @Rubén, yes I have just tested that by creating a shortcut to a .txt file, and when I open it on my hard drive, the file opens locally. This might be an improvement from before.

Answer (score 3):

Hallelujah.  [The article about the changes that Google made](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models) was my answer!

In the online UI in Google Drive, I navigated to the folder (not created by me) with the shared data.  I right clicked the folder and selected "Add Shortcut to Drive."  From there I navigated into **My Drive**, and then clicked "Add Shortcut."  Voila, now I can use my windows folders to see all the shared data!

Comment: What type of account do you have: G-Suite or a regular free account? And what sync client are you using: Backup & Sync or Drive File Stream?

Answer (score 3):

**Drive File Stream** does not show the shared shortcut if it is placed in the My Drive root folder, but it will show and sync if it is placed in a My Drive subfolder.

Create a folder in My Drive, for example 'SharedShortcuts'.
From 'Shared with Me', right click on a shared folder and choose 'Add shortcut' and place it into My Drive/SharedShortcuts.
Now you can see the shared folder link in the SharedShortcuts folder from your PC. When you click on the shared folder link it will create a temporary folder in .shortcut-targets-by-id hidden folder and you'll be able to see and open the shared files.

Comment: Interesting! Are you using mac or windows?

Comment: Drive File Stream is now **Google Drive for Desktop**. I'm not sure that this problem is still happening. Anyway, issues with the installable clients are better suited on [su], [apple.se] and [android.se] sites, depending on the platform used.