# How to move shared item to "my drive" (for later sync to harddrive) in Google drive

Tags: google-drive

Google recently made a change to how files are shared in Google Drive according to this article.

https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/04/10/google-completely-ruined-shared-folders-in-drive/

When this change first came about you could still access the "move to my drive" feature by the obscure **shift + z** shortcut.

It seems now however that this shortcut ALSO only offers the option of creating a link, just a dragging the item to "my drive" does now.

Was this a loop hole that Google decided to remove or have they hid the feature behind yet another obscure keyboard shortcut?

I apologize that the screenshot is in swedish, but the button now says "Add shortcut" where it previously said "Add" (as in "Add to my drive")

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access to "shared with me" folders?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/146144/how-can-i-access-to-shared-with-me-folders)

Comment: It only confirms the problem I was suspecting. Google is removing features from the workspace (suite) license level I am at. Rather than paying extra in order to keep the functionality we already had, I believe our organization will take our business elsewhere.

Comment: Please mark your question as a [duplicate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/146144/109353).